# Regular expression - delimiter problem in PHP

Tags: php, regex, extract

I'm trying to extract src attributes from: [attname src="http://example.org"] somecontent [attname src="http://www.example.com"]

What I have now:
`preg_match_all('#attname src=".*[^"]#', $buffer, $bufferarr);`

However it doesn't work - there's no stop after second `"`, what results in: `attname src="http://example.org"] somecontent [attname src="http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('#attname src="([^"]*)"#', $buffer, $bufferarr);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `+` and `*` are "greedy" - they gobble up as many characters as they can. That's why you get more than you want. If you add `?` to them (`+?` and `*?`) they will be non-greedy and will stop as soon as they can.

You regexp also looks wrong. It should be something like `#attname src="[^"]*?"#`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but anyways it get's the job done :

```
$str = '[attname src="http://example.org"] somecontent [attname src="http://www.example.com"]';
preg_match_all('/attname src=\"(.*?)\"/', $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```